# Converting an image into pencil sketch in opencv

Tags: c, opencv

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [I want to convert an image into pencil sketch in opencv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5675151/i-want-to-convert-an-image-into-pencil-sketch-in-opencv)

I have made the following code for the pencil sketch. But does it make a pencil sketch? Please see the result and comment how i can make it better.

```
int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
    int col_1, row_1;
    uchar b_1, g_1, r_1, b_2, g_2, r_2, b_d, g_d, r_d;

  IplImage* img = cvLoadImage( "input file");
  IplImage* img1 = cvCreateImage( cvSize( img->width,img->height ), img->depth, img->nChannels);
  IplImage* img2 = cvCreateImage( cvSize( img->width,img->height ), img->depth, img->nChannels);
  IplImage* dst = cvCreateImage( cvSize( img->width,img->height ), img->depth, img->nChannels);
  IplImage* gray= cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(img), img->depth, 1);

  cvNamedWindow("Input", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
  cvNamedWindow("Output", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );

  cvShowImage("Input", img );
  cvNot(img, img1);
  cvSmooth( img1, img2, CV_BLUR, 25,25,0,0);


   for( row_1 = 0; row_1 < img1->height; row_1++ )
 {
   for ( col_1 = 0; col_1 < img1->width; col_1++ )
   {
     b_1 = CV_IMAGE_ELEM( img1, uchar, row_1, col_1 * 3 );
     g_1 = CV_IMAGE_ELEM( img1, uchar, row_1, col_1 * 3 + 1 );
     r_1 = CV_IMAGE_ELEM( img1, uchar, row_1, col_1 * 3 + 2 );

     b_2 = CV_IMAGE_ELEM( img2, uchar, row_1, col_1 * 3 );
     g_2 = CV_IMAGE_ELEM( img2, uchar, row_1, col_1 * 3 + 1 );
     r_2 = CV_IMAGE_ELEM( img2, uchar, row_1, col_1 * 3 + 2 );

     b_d = b_1 + b_2;
     g_d = g_1 + g_2;
     r_d = r_1 + r_2;

     dst->imageData[img1->widthStep * row_1 + col_1* 3] = b_d;
     dst->imageData[img1->widthStep * row_1 + col_1 * 3 + 1] = g_d;
     dst->imageData[img1->widthStep * row_1 + col_1 * 3 + 2] = r_d;
   }
 }
   cvCvtColor(dst, gray, CV_BGR2GRAY);
   cvShowImage("Output", gray );

  cvWaitKey(0);
  cvReleaseImage( &img );
  cvReleaseImage( &gray);
  cvDestroyWindow("Input");
    cvDestroyWindow("Output");
}
```